# Proving by induction that the sequence $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3a_n-1}$ is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

$a_1=1$;  $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3a_n-1}$  $\quad$    $(n\ge1)$

Now I have to show it is true for $n=1$, which is easy. I have to assume it is true for $n=k$, therefore:

$\sqrt{3a_{k}-1}$ $\gt$ $\sqrt{3a_{k-1}-1}$

And I have to show that it is true for $n=k+1$ , so I have to prove:

$\sqrt{3a_{k+1}-1}$ $\gt$ $\sqrt{3a_{k}-1}$

Have I set this out correctly?

This is the point where I get stuck. From looking at it, it already looks like a very weak induction.

Comment: Hint: solve inequality $\sqrt{3x+1}\geq x \iff x\in [\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$, then you can prove each $a_n$ in this range instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inductive hypothesis is: $\sqrt{3a_{k} - 1} > a_{k}$.

In proving the $k \implies k+1$ case:

Remember that $\sqrt{3a_{k+1} - 1}$ can be re-written in terms of $a_k$.

Specifically:

$a_{k+1} = \sqrt{3a_{k} - 1}$; so your inequality becomes:

$$\sqrt{3\sqrt{3a_{k} - 1} - 1} > \sqrt{3a_{k} - 1} \iff 3\sqrt{3a_{k} - 1} - 1 > 3a_{k} - 1 \iff \sqrt{3a_{k} - 1} > a_{k}$$

where we have assumed positivity throughout, and the final inequality is your inductive hypothesis.

Comment: yes makes so much sense. I think the notation I was adopting was making everything unclear.

Comment: When I work out the limits I get two positive values, they are 0.38 and 2.61. I am told that $a_n$ < 3 for all n$\ge$1. So I know I am bounded above by 2.61, but what does that mean for 0.38? Is that the lower bound as my series approaches $\infty$? So far I have only encountered examples where my limit was a positive and negative, and the negative of course can easily be discarded. But this is not so here.

Comment: @anna_xox Note that the first term is $1$ and the sequence (in keeping with the post here!) is *increasing* -- so among $0.38$ and $2.61$ if every term is $\geq 1$ and the sequence converges, then the limit must be the latter, i.e., $a_n = 2.61\ldots$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Oh right I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 4):

First note that $a_n\geq 1\implies a_{n+1}\geq 1. $ So by induction,  the positive real number $a_{n+1}=\sqrt  {3 a_n-1}$ exists for every $n\in N.$

So the following is valid: $a_{n+2}>a_{n+1}\iff \sqrt {3 a_{n+1}-1}>\sqrt {3 a_n-1}\iff 3 a_{n+1}-1>3 a_n-1\iff a_{n+1}>a_n.$

The second equivalence in the above line is valid because $x\geq 1\implies 3 x-1>0.$